# First-hand sources for medieval urban life in central Europe

Tags: middle-ages, europe, social-history, everyday-life, sources

I am a teacher and I would like to do an exercise with my students concerning the urban life in the Middle Ages. I am looking for original, first-hand sources who describe urban life from the 11th century to the end of the 13th century, in central Europe (Flanders and France).

Does anyone know a source from an author who lived in the middle ages himself, describing what society in the cities was like back then?

Comment: The broader definition of Middle Ages spans 10 centuries, answers about the 5th century will be very different from answers about the 15th. Could you please narrow this down a bit? Also, some geographical limits would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. The span would be from the start of the 11th century to the end of the 13th century. Geographical limit would be Central Europe (Flanders and France).

Comment: Barbara Wertheim Tuchman in her excellent book 'A Distant Mirror: The Calamitous 14th Century' points out how hard it is to get a clear picture of ordinary life in that period. The available sources are contradictory. The period may be a little out but the lack of sources is lamentable. Life in the Stone Age is easier to reconstruct. Consider the difficulties in knowing details of life in England at the time of Shakespeare.

Comment: We don't do reference requests, see the FAQ.  Though I would suggest reading around in the sources at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics_of_English_towns_and_trade_in_the_Middle_Ages and the sources those sources cite.

Comment: I think there's a difference between asking for reference material and primary sources, @SamuelRussell. This is indeed a list-y question, but I don't think we risk ending up with a huge list of everyone's favourite book (which is what the guideline is trying to prevent).

Comment: As @ExpatEgghead mentions, the question is unfortunately too broad, as to avoid inconsistency you would need to list a lot of competing sources. I would suggest asking for secondary-aggregate sources; but then question is a reference request.

Comment: Have you read [this WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Chronicle_Society) yet? Or just buy the Encyclopedia of the Medieval Chronicle (two volumes), at 399 euros :)

Comment: I don't think this is a list question, because the number of available first-hand sources are so small that the result can hardly be called a list.

The rule against list questions are to prevent multiple answers that does not have a "best answer". Until we actually are in that situation, I don't see a need to close it.

Comment: Well, the National Archives in the UK has a large collection of papers from the relevant era. However, these tend to be official documents and direct documentation for the relevant period tend to be military correspondence which is not what I assume you are looking for. The vast majority are still on paper and would require a visit.

Comment: I will have a look at the Encyclopedia of Medieval Chronicle and A Distant mirror, they look very interesting indeed. As for the archive in the UK: I am actually looking for materials that describe society in the city as it was back then (mainly talking about crafts and trades and such).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a request for sources is off topic.

Comment: Perhaps it could be an idea to look at manorial rolls or urbariums. If you can read medieval Swedish you can have a look at https://stockholmskallan.stockholm.se/post/6871

Answer (score 2):

Emmanuel Le Roy Ladurie more or less founded [microhistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microhistory) with his book [Montaillou, village occitan de 1294 à 1324](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montaillou_(book)). Records of a certain religious inquisition were the author's principal source, and presumably you could satisfy your interest in primary sources by consulting them directly.